# SPARQL: How to restrict a variable to a namespace?

Tags: sparql, rdf

Consider the following SPARQL query:

```sql
PREFIX basics: <http://example.org/basic-knowledge/>
PREFIX special: <http://example.org/special-predicates/>

SELECT ?S ?P ?O
WHERE
{

 ?S ?P ?O.

}
```

This yields all triples.

How can I restrict the result to those triples where the predicate `?P` is from the namespace with the prefix `special:`?

Comment: You probably want to end the prefix URIs with "#" or "/" else `special:x` is  `http://example.org/special-predicatesx`.

Comment: You are right @AndyS, this was a typo. BTW: Is there any difference between `#` and  `/`?

Comment: At the basic level - no difference - they aren't even required but it makes for unreadable URIs and difficult to manage as linked data. Common practice has settled on two patterns `/` and `#`. There are many blogs about the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a string test. `str()` turns URIs into strings.

```
FILTER(strStarts(str(?P), str(special:)))
```

note the `special:` is replaced by the parser with the full URI: `http://example.org/special-predicates` so the executiuon is

```
FILTER(strStarts(str(?P), str(<ttp://example.org/special-predicates>)))
```

Runnable example:

```
PREFIX ns1: <http://example/>
PREFIX ns2: <http://ex/>

SELECT * {
 VALUES ?x { ns1:abc ns2:xyz }
 FILTER(strstarts(str(?x), str(ns1:)))
}
```